# PCIE Wake signal connection

Tags: schematics, pcie

I'm trying to connect a PCIE to USB 3.0 controller by Renesas UPD720201 but I'm not very sure how I should to connect with PCIE Raspberry Compute 4 PCIE lines.

On the Renesas guide design they connect Wake signal to Wake PCIE connector, but Raspberry Compute Module 4 doesn't have any  pcie wake connector, what should I do with this connector?

I realize that PCIE connector of Renesas design doesn't have any PCIE_REFCLK, while  Raspberry Compute Module 4 uses this connection.

Thank you.

UPD720201 PCIE Connections

[image: UPD720201 PCIE Connections]

Raspberry Compute Module 4 PCIE Connections.

[image]

Comment: Can you ask a question rather than making a few statements. Also, what does this mean `Compute Module 4 PCIE Connections.`?

Comment: Sorry @Andyaka , my mistake. Raspberry Compute Module 4 for all the cases.